# Why is the data of the "lightning-record-edit-form" field recorded if the value does not pass verification?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-recordeditform, updaterecord

**//html**

```
<template>
    <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-modal="true" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
                    <div class="slds-modal__container">
                        <header class="slds-modal__header slds-theme_shade">
                            <h1 class="title-modal slds-text-heading_medium">Edit Balance</h1>
                        </header>
                        <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium">
                            <lightning-record-edit-form
                                record-id={monthlyBalanceRecordId}
                                object-api-name={objectApiNameMonthlyExpense}
                                onsubmit={handleClickSaveEditedIncome}
                                onsuccess={handleSuccess}
                                onerror={handleError}>
                                <lightning-layout>
                                    <lightning-input-field field-name={BALANCE}>
                                    </lightning-input-field>
                                </lightning-layout>
                                <lightning-button
                                    class="slds-float_right"
                                    variant="brand"
                                    type="submit"
                                    label="Save">
                                </lightning-button>
                                <lightning-button
                                    class="slds-float_right"
                                    label="Cancel"
                                    onclick={handleClickCancelEditedIncome}>
                                </lightning-button>
                            </lightning-record-edit-form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
                <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
</template>
```

**//js**

```
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import MONTHLY_EXPENSE_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Monthly_Expense__c';
import BALANCE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Monthly_Expense__c.Balance__c';


export default class ExpensesPage extends LightningElement {

    @api objectApiNameMonthlyExpense = MONTHLY_EXPENSE_OBJECT;
    BALANCE = BALANCE_FIELD;
    @track monthlyBalanceRecordId;

    handleClickSaveEditedIncome(event){
            const fields = event.detail.fields;
            if(fields['Balance__c'] > 0){
                this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit(fields);
            } else {
                let message = 'The value cannot be negative!';
                console.log(message);
                this.handleNotification(message);
            }
    }

    handleSuccess(){
            this.dispatchEvent(new ShowToastEvent({
                title: "SUCCESS",
                variant: "success",
                }),
            );
    }

    handleError(){
        this.dispatchEvent(new ShowToastEvent({
            title: "ERROR!",
            variant: "error",
            }),
        );
    }

    handleNotification(message){
            this.dispatchEvent(new ShowToastEvent({
                title: message,
                variant: "info",
                }),
            );
    }
}
```

After I enter a **negative value** and click `Save`, I get the following:

[image]

I don't understand why the field value is updated? After all, in the `handleClickSaveEditedIncome` method, I get into `else` and get a **notification**(`handleNotification`), and `submit` should not happen... But I also get a **success toast**(`handleSuccess`)... I should get an **error toast** from the `HandleError` method and the record should not change... What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

you need to stop default submit action first then do your validation, if your validation pass then submit other wise skip the submission.

```
handleClickSaveEditedIncome(event){
 event.preventDefault(); // prevent the submit action
        const fields = event.detail.fields;
        if(fields['Balance__c'] > 0){
            this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit(fields);
        } else {
            let message = 'The value cannot be negative!';
            console.log(message);
            this.handleNotification(message);
        }
}
```

Comment: Oh, here's the thing... I had this line, but not where it is needed, it turns out. Thank you very much!